# How can I draw this kind of SVG

Tags: svg

I am working on someone else's code and there's no way of contacting them, and here's my issue:

```
<g 
        ng-attr-transform="translate({{node.width-18}}, 0) scale(0.6)"
        ng-mouseover="showArrowMenuTooltip($event, node);"
        ng-click="showArrowMenuTooltip($event, node);"
        ng-mouseleave="hideArrowMenuTooltip($event);"
        ng-attr-class="{{'flowchart-arrow-show-'+node.activity.act_task +' flowchart-arrow-set'}}">
        <!--Circle-->
        <path
          class="flowchart-arrow-circle"
          d="M16,1.466C7.973,1.466,1.466,7.973,1.466,16c0,8.027,6.507,14.534,14.534,14.534c8.027,0,14.534-6.507,14.534-14.534C30.534,7.973,24.027,1.466,16,1.466z"
        ></path>
        <!--Arrow-->
        <path 
          class="flowchart-arrow"
          d="M13.665,25.725l-3.536-3.539l6.187-6.187l-6.187-6.187l3.536-3.536l9.724,9.723L13.665,25.725z"
        ></path>
      </g>
```

That's some code inside an SVG tag that draws an arrow with a circle around it, my question is, suppose I want to draw an explanation mark, how would I do that?

I'm sure the `d="M13...` part is not written manually, yet i can't find online any documentation or tool that would help.

Comment: Why don't you google "svg path d". There are [plenty of tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Tools_for_SVG).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're after is called a 'Path' element.

Check this documentation out:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData

> A path is defined by including a ‘path’ element which contains a
>   d="(path data)" attribute, where the ‘d’ attribute contains the
>   moveto, line, curve (both cubic and quadratic Béziers), arc and
>   closepath instructions.
>
> Example triangle01 specifies a path in the shape of a triangle. (The M
>   indicates a moveto, the Ls indicate linetos, and the z indicates a
>   closepath).